# should I define another class for a django model

Tags: python, django, orm

A django model instance has a relation with database, while when I pass a object get from ModelName.objects.get() to upper layer. I don't want to expose its operation which can access the database, eg: save(), delete(). Thus, I currently define another class (say Product), inside which has attributes that almost the same as those in Model class (say ProductModel).
Every time I need the instance, I copy the attributes from one the the other. There should be better practice, isn't it?

```
from django.db import models
class ProductModel(models.Model):
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

class Product(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 1
        self.price = 12.3
```

Comment: If you don't save it in the views that reference the model (or the admin), then there's no access to the model. The user cannot directly access model instances, only submit data to a view.

Comment: Thanks. I am afraided I didn't express my problem well. If I return the model instance in one function, and in another module where I invoke that function, then the instance method is callable.

Comment: Yes, by *your code*. What exactly are you trying to protect yourself against?

Comment: @DanielRoseman maybe I need a copy of a model instance that no longer affect the original instance but as post of Robert Moskal said, that would "losing powerful features like the ability to lazy load relations and queries via QuerySets".

Answer (score 1):

You are describing the DTO (data transfer object) pattern, perhaps with an eye towards preventing client code from directly calling the CRUD methods on the models.

I think this pattern is unidiomatic in django. First of all, by not passing your models directly to your views and templating context, you are losing powerful features like the ability to lazy load relations and queries via QuerySets.

If you want to carry out certain business logic on your crud operations, there are a number of more django like solutions. Signals are one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/  You can use them to create pre and post save hooks. Client code can remain blissfully unaware of their operation.

Once you start having a good deal of business logic in your models, it is recommended to introduce a service object. Client code should interact through the service object whenever required. There's no hard way to ensure this, aside from convention, agreement, code reviews, and perhaps analysis tools.

Having said that, nothing precludes you from writing a simple mapper that converts django models to plain old python objects in your service layer. You just need to iterate trough the database fields on the model and set attributes on a python object or a dictionary, and then reverse the process on update operations. This strikes me as too much ceremony (and I might have chosen a technology that doesn't revolve around the ActiveRecord pattern as django does).